# Jquery selector for first 'one, two, three, and X' elements and :not()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

If you want to select the first element or :not, there are several choices:

- `:not(:first)`
- `:nth-child(1)`
- `first()`
- `:first-child`
- etc...

What are the options for selecting the first 'two, three, and X' elements?

**AND**

`:not(the first two, three, and X?)` 
can the `:not()` be accomplished by using the JS `!`

Comment: Define `X`, is this a consecutive number of elements?

Comment: What is "first two, three, and X" supposed to mean?

Comment: X, would any integer larger than 3.


'first two' elements, 'first three' elements, 'first X' elements,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the elements you want to exclude follow consecutively, you could use `slice()`:

```
$(selector).slice(0,3);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gE4DY/).

This will select the first three elements, the `0` is the zero-based index of the *first* element to start, and the second, the `3`, is the zero-based index of the element at which to stop, collecting.

The second number can also be a negative number and, if so, will count from the *end* of the returned set of elements:

```
$(selector).slice(1,-3);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/gE4DY/1/).

References:

- [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways:

For just the first 1 or 2 you could specify using `eq`: `$('.class').eq(0);`

For a limited range, use `lt`: `$('.class').lt(3);`

To perform the "not" of `lt`, use `gt`, which is greater-than.